# Fetch EditText value into dialog box, Also required addition for those user entered values

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, addition

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAg5W.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY11U.jpg)

Hi, I try to get dialogue box while clicking the "ADD" button....

Before that I would like to give you a small explanation what I need to achieve. Here I have listView items. The list includes items name and editText. User can enter values in this editText. Suppose a user enter three item values in the edit text(eg: Tomoto 30, Soup 40, Biriyani 50). Besides, there is an "ADD" Button which shows a pop up with a Dialog box on same screen when click. Inside of the Dialog box it must be shown item name and the user entered value, those total also required in case the above example(Tomoto 30, Soup 40, Biriyani 50..Total 120). If anyone can help it will be easy to forward and achieve my Application....Thanks in Advance

```
===========
 my_row.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="6dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_soup"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/itemNumber"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/description"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemNumber"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="0.00"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    ===========
    activity_main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.info.detail.textwatcher.MainActivity">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/my_row"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#46BB09">

           <!-- <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SEND QUERY"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ADD"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

        public Button button;
        public EditText ediText;
        TextView textView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            displayListView();
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            ediText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);


                    alertdialogbuilder.setTitle("Selected Items");


                        }
                    });
        }

        private void displayListView() {

            //Array list of products
            ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
            Product product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_soup, "Tomoto", "desc");
            productList.add(product);
            product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_soup, "Soup", "desc");
            productList.add(product);
            product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_biriyani, "Biriyani", "desc");
            productList.add(product);
            product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_soup, "Chilli", "desc");
            productList.add(product);
            product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_soup, "Powder", "desc");
            productList.add(product);
            product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_soup, "Apple", "desc");
            productList.add(product);
            product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_soup, "Orange", "desc");
            productList.add(product);
            product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_soup, "Banana", "desc");
            productList.add(product);
            product = new Product(R.drawable.ic_soup, "Mango", "desc");
            productList.add(product);


            //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
            dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.my_row, productList);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }

        private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

            private ArrayList<Product> productList;

            public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                   ArrayList<Product> productList) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, productList);
                this.productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
                this.productList.addAll(productList);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

                Product product = productList.get(position);

                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.my_row, null);
                    EditText quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                    //attach the TextWatcher listener to the EditText
                    quantity.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(view));

                }

                EditText quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                quantity.setTag(product);
                if (product.getQuantity() != 0) {
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(product.getQuantity()));
                } else {
                    quantity.setText("");
                }
                ImageView itemimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                itemimage.setImageResource(product.getItemimage());
                TextView itemNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemNumber);
                itemNumber.setText(product.getTitle());
                TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
                description.setText(product.getDescription());
                return view;

            }

        }

        private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

            private View view;

            private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
                this.view = view;
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //do nothing
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //do nothing
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
                int quantity = qtyString.equals("") ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(qtyString);

                EditText qtyView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                Product product = (Product) qtyView.getTag();
               product.setQuantity(quantity);

            }
        }
    }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

I will help you with some explanations and few lines of code, but it's up to you to continue research and write code.

First, make a class `AmountDialog` to extend `DialogFragment`. Override the `OnCreateDialog` method like this:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        //for this line you must create the layout for your dialog
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        //extract view references like this:
        final TextView amount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.amount);//here will be the id of the total 

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Total price")
                .setView(v)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OkButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do something with the amount:
                        String amountValue = amount.getText().toString();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.CancelButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //nothing here, it will dismiss by default
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
```

In MainActivity:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //note: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;!!!
              FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
              AmountDialog alert = new AmountDialog ();
              alert.show(fm, "AmountDialog");
                    }
                });
```

These would be the basic steps. Don't forget to create the layout for the dialog. And search how to manipulate the values extracted from the dialog through activities.